# Setting value in jagged dictionary sets all values

Tags: c#, dictionary, jagged-arrays

I have a jagged dictionary:

```
 Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, string>>> tierOptions = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, string>>>();
```

Later on, I have code that sets one of those values in the array:

```
 tierOptions[optionID][npID]["tName"] = cboTier.Text;
```

The problem is that when it runs through this portion of code, all "tName" elements are set to cboTier.Text instead of just the one element.

For instance if optionID was 1 and npID was 8, and I had these three:

```
 tierOptions[1][8]["tName"]
 tierOptions[2][8]["tName"]
 tierOptions[3][8]["tName"]
```

That particular line of code would set all three, instead of just tierOptions[1][8]["tName"]

Any idea why it is doing this?  Thanks!

Comment: tell us ho you initialize your dictionary (not array btw). You probably use the same object when you need to have different.

Comment: Sorry, there is an original dictionary that is added to the larger dictionary a few times, so that's probably where the issue lies.  However, this is how I initialize it, maybe you can tell me why it would be causing problems:

    tierOptions.Add(optionText, new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, string>>());
    tierOptions[optionText] = BestClass.tieringInfo;

Comment: So from the sounds of it, I should have a separately initialized dictionary, set that to tieringInfo, then add that into the main dictionary?

Comment: Not relevant to your question, but you should seriously consider using `var` in place of the variable type on the left side of your declaration.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation.  What would be the up-side to that besides less code?  Also, I noticed that tieringInfo was static when it shouldn't have been, but that didn't fix the issue.  I also have it setting a local variable first, then adding that to the dictionary, but they are all still getting changed when only one should be.

Comment: Terminology: this is neither "multi-dimensional" (it is "jagged"), nor an "array" (it is a set of dictionaries)

Comment: Marc, thank you for the clarification.  I have updated the tags to prevent confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds simply like you have used the same dictionary instance in several "dimensions" (your terminology). Since this is a reference, they are all shared (there is no automatic clone-into-isolated-copies here).

When filling the data, take care to use isolated dictionary instances when the data should be separate.

Comment: That's exactly what it sounds like.  When the form is first loaded, it pulls in the base information.  Each addition to the dictionary should add in a clone of that initial information.  What is the best way to create this clone?

Comment: After a quick test, I did verify that that is in fact the problem.  However, instead of gathering the data multiple times, I'd like to get it once, store it in the variable, then duplicate the jagged dictionary if possible.  I've done some quick searches and this doesn't seem very simple to implement.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Yep, I would say the sae as Marc.
Please take a look at this example how you can retreive the vlaue from your type of Dictionary:

```
        Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, string>>> dic = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, string>>>();
        //add to 1st dic:
        dic.Add("A", new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, string>>());
        //add to 2nd dic:
        dic["A"].Add(1, new Dictionary<string, string>());
        //add to 3rd dic:
        dic["A"][1].Add("a", "value 1");

        //string KeyIn3rdDic = dic["A"][1].ToString();
        string ValueIn3rdDic = dic["A"][1]["a"]; //result is "value 1";
```